# js mousedown with touch

Tags: javascript, touch, right-click

is there a way to detect whether a 'mousedown' is a touch right click (hold the finger about 1 sec in place) or just a normal right click?

I think chrome can do this with "ev.originalEvent.sourceCapabilities.firesTouchEvents". But only chrome.

```
$('#container').mousedown(function(ev) {
    if (ev.button === 2 && ev.comesFromTouch) return false
    //...
}
```

edit:
current situation: after about one second after I pressed down my left mouse button, the browser automaticly triggers a 'mousedown' event with button = 2 (tested in the 'device toolbar' mode in chrome). I want to cancel this.

**SOLUTION**
If a right mousedown appears between a touchstart and touchend it is a right click on a touch screen.

it works something like this.

```
function onPcRight() { console.log(1);}
function onTouchRight() { console.log(2);}

$('#container').mousedown(function(ev) {
    if (ev.button === BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        if ($(this).prop('touchdown')) onTouchRight();
        else onPcRight();
    }
})
.on('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).prop('touchdown', true);
})
.on('touchend', function() {
    $(this).prop('touchdown', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use setTimeout/clearTimeout to count 1s. The pseudo code:

```
var global_timer = null;
$('#container').mousedown(function(ev) {
  if (ev.button === 2) {
    global_timer = setTimeout(fireTouchRightClick, 1000);
  }
});
$('#container').mousemove(function(ev) {
  cancelTouchRightClick();
});
$('#container').mouseleave(function(ev) {
  cancelTouchRightClick();
});
$('#container').mouseup(function(ev) {
  if (cancelTouchRightClick() && ev.button === 2) {
    fireNormalRightClick();
  }
});
function cancelTouchRightClick () {
  if (global_timer) {
    clearTimeout(global_timer);
    global_timer = null;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
function fireTouchRightClick () {
  global_timer = null;
  // TODO touch right click
}
```

I also found a repo to do mouse holding on Github: https://github.com/dna2github/dna2petal/tree/master/visualization
https://github.com/dna2github/dna2petal/blob/master/samples/visualization.html

Maybe you need to pass button type to the mousehold event callback

Comment: Thanks for your effort :), but I meant something else .
current situation:
after about one second the browser automaticly triggers a 'mousedown' event with button = 2 (tested in the 'device toolbar' mode in chrome). I want to cancel this.